# How to connect Picker view to Table view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uipickerview, uipickerviewcontroller

I have a picker view in place which works perfectly. I want to connect it to a table view where once a selection is made in the picker, it takes you straight to the table view for each individual selection. How do I connect my picker view to the table view? I have looked everywhere but can't find an answer to this question.

Comment: You mean to say that your TableView data is dependent on PickerView Data Selection??

Comment: To answer the question you would have to tell us at least how the data in the pickerview is related to the table. For example, does the pickerview refer to different arrays that you want to use to populate the table? Or are you trying to use the same data from the pickerview, and present it in a table? Also, are the pickerview and the tableview in two different viewcontrollers?